# What's the best way of debug with Eclipse a SBT-based webapp

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a standard webapp made with `Scala`/`Java`.
I use `SBT` and [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) and I can easily start my app with:

```
sbt container:start
```

How can I easily debug it with Eclipse and IDEA (Community edition)?

The first solution I can think of, is to enable remote debugging, launch it with SBT and attach the debugger.

Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    javaOptions in container ++= Seq(
      "-Xdebug",
      "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
    ),
```

Comment: I've used also this solution.  I've created a command that eases to pass different options to the container.